# how does casperjs waitforselector work?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to write a program that opens a link, and then waits for a specific selector to appear. I am using the latest version of casperjs and phantomjs. I am running my program on a mac. In order to wait for my selector, I used this.waitForSelector. Most of the time, the function seems to work as intended, but sometimes it says the selector is there when it isn't, and then the program tries to access aforementioned selector and, naturally, crashes. I can't tell if my code is bad or if it's an issue with casperjs. Any insight would be much appreciated, thanks!

```
function addLinks(link) {
this.waitForSelector("tr a", function() {
    this.echo(this.getHTML("tr a"));
    this.echo("I'm sure tr a is available in the DOM");
    var found = this.evaluate(searchLinks);
    this.echo(found.length + " links found on " + link);
    for(var x = 0;x < found.length;x++){
        this.echo(found[x]);
    }
    links = links.concat(found);
    fs.write("forever.txt", links, 'a');
    next();
},function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
    this.echo("I can't haz my screenshot.");

    if(this.getHTML("span.numResults") == "(No Results)"){
        this.echo("nothing doing " + curr);
        next();
    }
    else{
        curr += String(alphabet[0]);
    }
    this.echo("curr " + curr);
});
```

}

Comment: `sometimes it says the selector is there when it isn't` How can you tell? I mean if it says selector is found it probably did find it in DOM. Why are you sure the selector is not there?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems right, I suggest you use a more specific selector, maybe is a pattern that shows up somewere else in the HTML because it's a little bit generic. Can we see the HTML code?